# Drywall around 10x10 electrical box

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall

I have a roughly 14" * 14" hole in my ceiling, after an electrician put a junction box there. The box is a flush 10x10 box, and I want to be able to remove the lid later. The lid right now is close to flush to the bottom finished side of the 1/2" drywall. I don't have a lot of experience with drywall, and I'm especially puzzled on how to make a nice transition to this box (which does not have a mud ring). I could cut back the sheetrock a bit on each side to expose half of the joists. Would you recommend one large piece of drywall with a hole cut for the box?

[image: Hole in drywall around box]

[image: Side view of box]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it's a textured ceiling and that would be hard to match if you cut back to the joists. You probably won't need to remove the lid to this box very often but it does have to be accessible. Have you thought about just attaching a 14"x 14" or 16"x 16" register over the box? It would make it less of an eye sore but still be accessible. Maybe use magnets like Jasen commented on.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Codevio..  can't bury boxes in a way that requires disassembly of the building.

Comment: would it be acceptable to use magnets to hold the register on instead of screws?

Comment: Hard to say what an AHJ would do . Easy enough to open, but not obvious that it does open.

Comment: You could even open the vents up enough to see the screws to the lid.. I'd take my chances.

Comment: That is a brilliant idea. Would you do any drywall around the box, or just cover it all with a vent?

Comment: @Christian K  If it vents into an attic you'd want to stuff some insulation  around the box  but I wouldn't bother with the drywall unless you wanted the practice.. Good luck.

Comment: They make access panel kits for this very purpose... as clever as this idea may be, it's still a hack, and code/ordinance violations should be considered.

Comment: @tahwos  Have you seen those Installed in a nice living room??  They look pretty bad. I've installed about 12  of these "hacks"  over the last 55 years and the clients have loved them over the alternatives.  Three were inspected after the fact  and passed with flying colors..

Comment: @JACK Yes, I have, and if done correctly they look the part too. I'm not going split hairs with you, on what you got away with and what you didn't, or what 12 customers supposedly settled for... most will accept a contractor's word at face value anyway - that's why so many get ripped off, by some guy with a ladder on his truck and phone number on the door, who doesn't know how to properly install an access panel.

Answer (score 4):

### You need a *flush mount cover* for that box

What your electrician did was install a standard NEMA 1 (indoor) enclosure/pull box there, and these by and large come by default set up to be *surface mounted* with their back to a wall, for use in industrial applications and utility spaces.  However, for a finished application, you need to fit a *flush mount cover* of the correct size to the box instead of the stock surface mounted cover.  It looks like you'll also have to unmount and remount the box, with the breaker for that circuit or circuits off, so that it is actually *flush* with the finished surface, instead of being recessed slightly, as the flush cover won't fit properly otherwise.

Comment: Learn something new everyday, I didn't even know flush mount junction box covers larger than 4 11/16" square were readily available. This is the ideal solution, particularly if the hole size in the drywall is planned in advance (there will likely be some drywall work required on the side with the largest gap with this solution unless the cover's flange is huge). You will also likely need to go to a dedicated electrician's supply store for this type of cover.

Comment: @statueuphemism -- NEMA-type pull boxes/enclosures are kind of their own world :)

Answer (score 2):

While JACKs suggestion disguises the box well and removes the need for drywall work, it also is a potential code violation and makes it so someone in the future might not even know the box is there (it will look like a return air vent for an hvac system).

That said, they make code-friendly covers called "Access Panels" explicitly for this purpose--you can even buy ones with spring clips that allow the panel to be secured directly to the drywall so you don't even have to figure out how to fasten it in place. This solution might not blend in as well as a return air grille since return air ducts in ceilings are more common, but access points to electrical boxes also shouldn't be hidden.

Comment: you can bend those vents  so you can see the box and the screws from the ground.  You'd certainly see the box if you ever changed the light bulb.